# How to use dexie with typescript and requirejs?

Tags: typescript, requirejs, dexie

I have a typescript project which is using requirejs to load jquery so I know the basic concept works. I am trying to get dexie set up and I just can't get it working.

My require config looks like this:

```
require.config({

    baseUrl: '',

    paths: {
        //main libraries
        jquery: 'scripts/jquery-2.2.1',
        dexie: 'node_modules/dexie/dist/dexie.min'
    },

    shim: {
        jquery: {
            exports: '$'
        }
    }
});
```

I can include this in a require() like the following and it works, so I know the path is ok.

```
require(['jquery', 'dexie'], function ($) {
    $(document).ready(() => {
        alert('all good');
    });
});
```

However, when I do this:

```
import dexie = require('dexie');
```

Typescript complains that 'dexie' cannot be found.

The actual doco says to do:

```
import Dexie from 'dexie';
```

but that doesn't work either.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably that you need the `dexie.d.ts` file. The best way to install type definition file sis using [typings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typings).

```
$ npm install -g typings
$ typings init
$ typings install dexie --save --ambient
```

Then add a reference to it:

```
/// <reference path="./typings/browser.d.ts"/>

import Dexie = require('dexie');

var db = new Dexie('MyDatabase');
```

You need to set the compiler options to compile the modules into AMD modules.

Comment: It tells me "Cannot find module 'dexie'".

Comment: Id the file `./typings/browser.d.ts``available? If not, is a file `./typings/index.d.ts` available?

Answer (score 0):

There ended up being some issues with the dexie package which the author was awesome at addressing.